# Copy two Excel ranges, paste combined data on next available row of a separate worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy two column ranges on one worksheet to the next available row on a separate worksheet.

What I have below is pasting the second range to a new row rather than combining it into the same one.

```vb
Sub copyText1()

Range("B8:B18").Copy

Sheets("FinalTestData").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True

Range("D6:D49").Copy

Sheets("FinalTestData").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

I believe I understand why this is happening since the code is essentially repeating itself so it should be creating two new rows.  I just don't understand how to combine this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Sub copyText1()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, c As Range, addr, rngCopy As Range
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set c = Sheets("FinalTestData").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 'initial paste
    
    For Each addr In Array("B8:B18", "D6:D49") 'loop over ranges to be copied
        Set rngCopy = ws.Range(addr)
        rngCopy.copy
        c.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, _
                        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
        Set c = c.Offset(0, rngCopy.Rows.Count) 'move paste destination to the right
    Next addr

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach, which bypasses the clipboard.

```
Sub copyText1()
   With Sheets("FinalTestData")
       Dim rng As Range
       Set rng = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
   End With

   Dim copy1 As Range
   Set copy1 = ActiveSheet.Range("B8:B18")

   With copy1
       rng.Resize(,.Rows.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(.Value)
   End With

   Dim copy2 As Range
   Set copy2 = ActiveSheet.Range("D6:D49")

   With copy2
       rng.Offset(,copy1.Rows.Count).Resize(,.Rows.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(.Value)
   End With
End Sub
```